# Are immigration officers who grant visas to a convicted terrorist guilty of a crime?

Tags: immigration, security

I'm not a lawyer or an expert on laws, but from what I know it is the visa officers' first and foremost responsibility to screen applicants/referrals and filter out potentially dangerous ones. They get paid from taxpayers money just to do it, and if they are so incompetent as to admit a blood thirsty psychopathic terrorist who later attacks people with a car and a butcher knife, shouldn't victims and/or their families have the right to sue them? And if they do, are they likely to win?

Comment: At least in the US, you can sue anyone for anything. So, yes the victims and/or families have the right to sue. I don't know how likely they are to win, however.

Comment: Do you know of a case where visas where granted to known convicted terrorists?

Comment: Whether someone can be sued, and whether they are guilty of a crime, are very different questions; almost unrelated.  Which do you want to know about?  Also, what country's laws do you want to know about?  We can't tell you about all of them.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Both answer assume this involves U.S. immigration law (obviously if another nation's law applies those answers aren't applicable). I don't think that there is a question over whether the visa officer has committed a crime. The hypothetical is that the immigrant granted a visa who should not have been granted a visa committed a crime, and the actual question is whether the visa officer has any legal civil liability for the harm caused by the crime committed by the immigrant who was wrongfully given a visa.

Comment: @ohwilleke: The title of the question asks whether they are guilty of a crime.  (That's after edit by BlueDogRanch; the original title asked whether they would be guilty of "second-degree murder".)  So I assume it may be a question the OP wants answered.  I agree the answer is almost certainly "no".

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point. The analysis would obviously be different, but your conclusion that the answer is "no" would surely be correct, among other reasons because federal employees are immune from state criminal prosecutions while carrying out their duties and because nothing more than negligence is suggested which isn't a basis for a murder conviction, and because causation is remote, and because of governmental immunity.

Comment: @mikeazo the suit would most likely be dismissed because the visa officeris most likely immune. So it is at least arguable that the answer is "no, you can't sue the visa officer in this case."

Comment: Can you sue them if they let in a US post office employee coming back from holiday, who has never committed a crime in his life, and when he goes back to work, he "goes postal"? Or are you fine with a gun and just object to the car and the butchers' knife?

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @BlueDogRanch is right as far as it goes, but omits a critical point. There are certain acts that are excluded from liability under the Federal Tort Claims Act and granting a visa when it should have been denied is almost certainly one of them. The critical provisions are 28 USC § 2680(a) and (h).

> 28 USC § 2680. Exceptions to the Federal Tort Claims Act
>
> The provisions of this chapter and section 1346(b) of this title shall
>   not apply to--
>
> (a) **Any claim** based upon an act or omission of an employee of the
>   Government, exercising due care, in the execution of a statute or
>   regulation, whether or not such statute or regulation be valid, or
>   **based upon the exercise or performance or the failure to exercise or
>   perform a discretionary function or duty on the part of a federal
>   agency or an employee of the Government, whether or not the discretion
>   involved be abused.** . . .
>
> (h) Any claim arising out of assault, battery, false imprisonment,
>   false arrest, malicious prosecution, abuse of process, libel, slander,
>   misrepresentation, deceit, or interference with contract rights:
>   Provided, That, with regard to acts or omissions of investigative or
>   law enforcement officers of the United States Government, the
>   provisions of this chapter and section 1346(b) of this title shall
>   apply to any claim arising, on or after the date of the enactment of
>   this proviso, out of assault, battery, false imprisonment, false
>   arrest, abuse of process, or malicious prosecution. For the purpose of
>   this subsection, "investigative or law enforcement officer" means any
>   officer of the United States who is empowered by law to execute
>   searches, to seize evidence, or to make arrests for violations of
>   Federal law.

The decision to grant or deny a visa is generally placed in the discretion of a visa officer, evaluating the facts when informed by guidelines established by the U.S. Secretary of State and Department of Homeland Security which is a quasi-judicial role, and is subject to administrative appeal in some cases. As a result, even if that discretion is abused, the employee and the agency are immune from liability under the FTCA.

The claim may be barred under 2680(h), as well, if the visa officer is sued for conspiring to cause one of the enunciated intentional torts and the visa officer is not a law enforcement officer.

Also, if liability exists at all under the FTCA, it [arises against the United States and not against the employee personally](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/usao/legacy/2010/12/06/usab5806.pdf):

> The general rule is that **federal employees enjoy absolute immunity
>   from tort claims that challenge negligent or wrongful acts performed
>   while acting within the scope of government employment.** *See Osborn v.
>   Haley*, 549 U.S. 225, 229-30 (2007). The source of this absolute
>   immunity is the Federal Employees Liability Reform and Tort
>   Compensation Act of 1988, commonly known as the Westfall Act. 28
>   U.S.C. § 2679 (2010). Under the Westfall Act, the exclusive remedy for
>   anyone injured by the negligent or wrongful act of a federal employee
>   acting in the scope of employment is a suit against the United States
>   under the Federal Tort Claims Act. 28 U.S.C. § 2679(b)(1) (2010).

The bottom line is that there are no private causes of action that arise under the immigration laws for a person not personally claiming improper denial of an immigration benefit. *Cf. Mirmehdi v. United States*, 662 F.3d 1073, Footnote 4 (9th Cir. 2011) (no cause of action exists for selective enforcement of the immigration laws); *Tsolmon v. United States*, 15-20609 (5th Cir. November 7, 2016) (discretionary exception clause barred FTCA action for failure to follow department policy re potential visa issue). *But see Watson v. United States*, 14-CV-6459 (E.D. New York, February 25, 2016) (discretionary acts exception did not apply to the deportation of a child who was a known U.S. citizen by immigration officers since this is beyond the scope of their authority).

There is also no constitutional right to have the government deny a visa to someone not entitled to a visa under U.S. law or immigration guidelines.

If someone brought a suit of the kind described in the question, they would almost certainly lose, probably on a motion to dismiss by the government filed before they were required to answer the complaint on the merits.

A sufficiently negligent decision might constitute good cause to fire the visa officer from that person's civil service job, if their supervisor chose to seek the termination of the visa officer's employment.

I will refrain from answering whether the sovereign immunity that exists in this circumstance is good policy as the question asks as that would be beyond the scope of this forum and implicate wide ranging questions of pure opinion. Suffice it to say that U.S. law on this question would not necessarily apply in every country.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for individuals to sue the federal government (which typically has sovereign immunity) for negligence, and sometimes they are successful, but the lawsuit must be very focused to be allowed under the Federal Tort Claims Act https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Tort_Claims_Act which allows only some types of actions against the government. (And, before any suit is filed by a plaintiff under the FTCA, they must first file a complaint with the specific federal agency.)

A very general overview of the possibilities of suing the government is from Nolo:

> Historically, under the doctrine of "sovereign immunity," you were not
>   permitted to sue the king. Sovereign immunity has carried over to
>   modern times in the form of a general rule that you cannot sue the
>   government -- unless the government says you can.
>   http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/suing-government-negligence-FTCA-29705.html

So, it is possible, but the process is complex and is designed to both allow lawsuits as a "check and balance" of actions and possible negligence by federal employees, as well as to stop frivolous suits.

Can a federal immigration officer be sued for negligence for issuing visas?

Yes, under certain circumstances. These are very general guidelines *(with my emphasis)* on the limitations of FTCA claims; anything else would be thrown out early in any lawsuit:

> *Only federal employees can be sued under the FTCA*, not independent
>   contractors hired by the federal government (unless they are treated
>   like employees).
>
> The *negligent or wrongful conduct must have been done within the scope
>   of the defendant's employment*.
>
> In general, *only claims of negligence -- as opposed to intentional
>   misconduct -- are allowed* (though some claims for intentional
>   misconduct can be brought against certain federal law enforcement
>   officers).
>
> The claim must be based on -- and permitted by -- *the law of the state
>   in which the misconduct occurred.*

And, before a suit is filed under the FTCA, the plaintiff must first file a claim with the federal agency responsible - probably multiple agencies - and work through that process first. The government has its own site for that process and guidelines: https://www.usa.gov/complaint-against-government

How likely they are to win depends on the merits of the case; what's the evidence an employee was negligent? And if the plaintiff is trying to prove intent: again, what's the evidence?

Comment: In fact, the question almost surely falls within an exception to the FTCA.

Comment: True, I didn't see those exceptions, and granting a visa is discretionary.

Comment: To further muddy the waters, the alleged negligence may have occurred at an embassy in a foreign country.  Do US courts have jurisdiction, and does the FTCA apply?

Comment: Another part of 28 USC § 2680 excludes liability for actions in a foreign country, but I believe that for that purpose actions taken at an embassy are deemed to take place in a territory of the United States as U.S. embassies are in the sovereign country of the U.S. and are immune to local laws in that location.

Comment: @ohwilleke as I understand it, embassies enjoy immunity, but they are not extraterritorial.

Comment: @phoog I've seen definitive statements that they are extraterritorial, but this was not convincing to the 9th Circuit in one of the rare FTCA cases applying to an embassy that I was able to locate. *Meredith v. United States*, 330 F.2d 9 (9th Cir. 1964) (holding that U.S. embassy in Thailand was a foreign country for the purposes of an FTCA negligence claim allegedly what would normally be a state law tort).

Comment: @ohwilleke Who made these definitive statements? Most such statements I've seen seem to rely on some Vienna convention or another, which of course has little bearing on how a given country treats its own foreign missions in its own legal system. For example, countries seem to treat international airports somewhat differently (and for different purposes); I would not be surprised if the same were true of embassies.

Comment: @ohwilleke related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/2318/6927.  A related line of reasoning: suppose an assault occurred at an embassy in Washington, DC.  Would the foreign country have to transport the assailant abroad to conduct a trial in its own court system?  More likely, they would turn the accused over to the local police, which is possible because the embassy is not in fact foreign territory (if it were, local courts would have no jurisdiction).

Comment: @phoog The criminal jurisdiction of the federal courts over crimes committed inside a U.S. embassy was established in *U.S. v. Erdos*, 474 F.2d 157 (4th Cir. 1973). Most people present at a foreign embassy in D.C. are immune from criminal liability and a foreign embassy may not be searched or entered by U.S. law enforcement. http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/150546.pdf Few embassies would turn nationals over to local authorities. Foreign military forces in the U.S. can court-martial their own people. 22 USC 701 et seq.

Comment: See United States v. Erdos, 474 F.2d 157, 159 (4th Cir. 1973) (characterizing “United States Embassy in Equatorial Guinea” as “a part of the territory of the United States.”); United States v. Morton, 314 F. Supp. 2d 509, 512 (D. Md. 2004) (similar); Pashby v. Commissioner, 25 T.C.M. (CCH) 667, 668 (1966) (similar); United States v. Archer, 51 F. Supp. 708 (S.D. Cal. 1943), which stated that “[a] consulate . . . . is a part of the territory of the United States of America,” id. at 709.

Comment: See 158 Cong. Rec. H5864 (daily ed. Sep. 12, 2012) (statement of Rep. Poe) (“Both of these places are U.S. sovereign soil, the consulate and the Embassy.”); id. at H5918 (statement of Rep. Gohmert) (similar); 158 Cong. Rec. H5966 (daily ed. Sep. 13, 2012) (statement of Rep. Garrett) (similar).

Comment: Embassies are “[b]eyond the geographic limits of” the countries in which they were located. Black’s Law Dictionary 666 (9th ed. 2009). “The premises . . . of an accredited diplomatic mission . . . are immune from any exercise of jurisdiction by the receiving state that would interfere with their official use.” Restatement (Third) of the Foreign Relations Law of the United States § 466 (1987).

Comment: You all should compile these comments and points into another answer to the original question.